Assigning OwnerID to Task in Test
When creating tasks in test I am unable to assign an Owner ID (user) - insert task fails with cross reference error.
// Create a Task record
    System.runAs(systemAdmin){
    Task task = new Task();
    task.Priority = 'Normal';
    task.Status = 'Open';
    task.ActivityDate = Date.today().addDays(3);
    task.Subject = 'Test Task';
    task.WhatId = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Child Account 1' LIMIT 1].Id;
    task.OwnerId = manager1Id;
    tasks.add(task);
    System.debug('Created by: ' + task.CreatedBy.Id);
    System.debug('Created by Profile Name: ' +task.CreatedBy.Profile.Name);
    System.debug('Task Owner ID: ' + task.OwnerId);
    System.debug('Task What ID: ' + task.WhatId);
    
    // Trigger fires here 
    System.debug('*******TASK INSERT********* - if nothing follows, task insert failed');
    insert tasks;        
    System.debug('Task Owner ID after insert: ' + task.OwnerId);
    System.debug('Created by after insert: ' + task.CreatedBy.Id);
    System.debug('Created by Profile Name after insert: ' +task.CreatedBy.Profile.Name);
    }

So when I comment out the task.OwnerId = manager1Id; the task is successfully inserted - still without an owner or a created by Id.

Really lost on this, any help is appreciated thank you in advance.
Adding Logs when OwnerId is specified:

Lastly, the actual error message when OwnerId is specified:
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []  
                                                 Class.TaskHelperTest.TaskReassignmentTrigger: line 288, column 1 

I have used User and Group Ids for the OwnerId, results are the same.

what license type is the manager user? do you get the same error if the owner is the system admin user?

is the manager1Id an active user?

'Salesforce' is the license for the manager profile.
When using the system admin as the owner on the task, it looks like it is able to insert the task though and that is great news.
System Admin ID in test: 005Hs00000COU5ZIAX
Task Owner ID: 005Hs00000COU5ZIAX
Task What ID: 001VG000007ncuaYAA
TASK INSERT** - if nothing follows, task insert failed
Task Owner ID after insert: 005Hs00000COU5ZIAX

@cropredy Yes, all users are active here.

UPDATE:
Seems when the System.runAs(user) is a System Admin, I can assign the task to the system admin.
When the System.runAs(user) is 'manager1' I can insert the task assigned to System Admin, but not when assigning the task to manager1 (the running user). Running as system admin and assigning to the manager 1 does not insert either.

Seems the manager can not assign to themselves for some reason.
FLS shows the field is available to the profiles in use.
Accessibility shows the WhatID is Read-Only based on page layout, but when I go to page layout the field is not checked for Read-Only (nor required).
